# How to integrate source section in chat gpt API in py?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I need to add a sources section containing the parts from which the document gathers the information it provides to the user in an AI created using ChatGPT APIs.
The langchain docs include example for configuring?

```
def get_vectorstore(text_chunks):
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(texts=text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    return vectorstore

def get_conversation_chain(vectorstore):
    llm = ChatOpenAI()

    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history', return_messages=True)
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        memory=memory
    )
    return conversation_chain

def handle_userinput(user_question):
    response = st.session_state.conversation({'question': user_question})
    st.session_state.chat_history = response['chat_history']
    for i, message in enumerate(st.session_state.chat_history):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            st.write(user_template.replace(
                "{{MSG}}", message.content ), unsafe_allow_html=True)
        else:
            st.write(bot_template.replace(
                "{{MSG}}", message.content), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```